# How to mock composable for unit testing Vuejs3 components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vitest

I want to write unit tests for my component. My component is Date & Time picker bar what emits users selected date. For that component uses external library [VueDatePicker](https://vue3datepicker.com) the logic is what if user selected date and time when on pressing button with name "Parādīt" it will launch function to emit to parent compont new time. But if time was not selected nothing happens.

I moved time, date variable and isDateSet function what returns true if user selected time into composable. Named useDate. I already wrote unit tests for this composable but I can not mock composable what function isDateSet return true for example when I need.

For example I have test

```js
// all needed imports are all above
const wrapper = shallowMount(TheTimePickerBar);
describe("The Time Picker Bar", () => {
    it("Component emit date  if isDateSet() returns true", () => {    
        wrapper.vm.isDateSet = vi.fn().mockReturnValue(true); // mock composable function what is used in compoonent but is not mocked in emitSelectedDate is still false
        wrapper.vm.emitSelectedDate(); // event what is fired when user click on show btn
        expect(wrapper.emitted('selected-date')).toBeTruthy(); // return false
    });
  });
```

```
tests/TheTimePickerBar.spec.ts > The Time Picker Bar > component  emit date if isDateSet() returns true
AssertionError: expected undefined to be true // Object.is equality

- Expected:
true

+ Received:
undefined

 ❯ tests/TheTimePickerBar.spec.ts:35:50
```

my composable

```js
import { Ref, ref } from "vue";

interface Time {
  hours: number;
  minutes: number;
  seconds: number;
}

export function useDate() {
  const date = ref(new Date());
  const time: Ref<Time> = ref({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
  const isValidDate: Ref<undefined | boolean> = ref(undefined);
  const isValidTime: Ref<undefined | boolean> = ref(undefined);

  const isDateSet = (): boolean => {
    if (!time.value.hours) {
      isValidTime.value = false;

      return false;
    }

    isValidTime.value = undefined;
    isValidDate.value = undefined;

    date.value.setHours(
      time.value.hours,
      time.value.minutes,
      time.value.seconds
    );

    return true;
  };

  return { date, time, isValidDate, isValidTime, isDateSet };
}
```

How it is used inside TheTimePickerBar.vue

```js
<template>
// <!-- some components from bootstrap vue and VueDatePicker component what "returns" value of date and time by v-mode -->
    <b-button
     @click="emitSelectedDate"
     variant="primary"
     class="btn-max-width"
    >
        Parādīt
    </b-button>
</template>
  
<script setup lang="ts">

import { useDate }from '@src/composables/useDate.ts'

import { constants } from '@src/constants/constants';

import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';

const emit = defineEmits<{
    selectedDate: [date: string]
}>();
// Here is destructing composable where all are reactive variables except isDateSet its function
const { date, time, isValidDate, isValidTime, isDateSet } = useDate(); 

// method what if isDateSet() returns true emits date variable to parent component
const emitSelectedDate = ((): void => {
    console.log('component isDateSet()',isDateSet()); // here whenever I mocked isDateSet() function it returns false
    if(isDateSet())
      emit('selectedDate',  date.value.toString());
});
</script>
```

What I tried:

- using vi.fn() mock return value of the function but still is emitSelectedDate()
- tried of using vi.mock to mock all composable but only got error message
  [image: TypeError error from ts if mocking by vi.mock composable]

My stack contains

- vuejs3 all components are written in compose API style,
- vue test utils
- for unit tests vitest instead of jest(same problem with using jest).

How to mock composables in vuejs3 when Compose API was used to create components?

Comment: What exactly did you try? It's easier to fix existing code rather than write it from scratch, only to find out that you tried the same thing that didn't work for some other reason

Comment: I tried using vi.mock() to mock the entire useData composable in unit tests of TheTimePickerBar component and weird $setup.locale Typeerror showed instead. Second approach showed in first code axample where I "mocked" isDataSet() function with vi.fn() {code example wrapper.vm.isDateSet = vi.fn().mockReturnValue(true);} But still is not working.

Comment: You can't efficiently mock composition api with wrapper.vm because there's no `this` in script part, second approach is not an option. "I tried using vi.mock() to mock" - please, provide code, the question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no `locale()` the error refers to, also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors